# How do I create and modify an associative array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects, associative-array

I'm trying to move some code from server side to client side. I'm struggling to work with Javascript. It seeems what I need to achieve uses objects vs arrays.

I have some input fields with data attributes that I loop through.

```
$(".selection:checked").each(function(){

    $selection_id=$(this).data('selection_id');
    $swatch_id=$(this).data('swatch_id');

});
```

Firstly, I want to create an array in the following form:

```
$array[$selection_id]=$swatch_id;
```

ie `array(100=>123,200=456,300=789)`

Secondly, I want to loop through a list of elements and swap out a value according to the array key.

ie `element has key 100 and value 1000 then:`

```
$array[100]=1000;
```

New array is `array(100=>1000,200=456,300=789)`

Finally, I need to take that array and turn it into a string in the form:

```
"100:1000,200:456,300:789"
```

I'm new to Javascript and still struggling to get my head around objects. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please add the HTML code too will help to check scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You better create an object for storing the $selection_id => $watch_id mapping. You can achieve it using following syntax

```
const mapping = {};
mapping[$selection_id] = $watch_id;
```

Then this `array(100=>123,200=456,300=789)` will look like

```
mapping = {
   100: 123,
   200: 456,
   300: 789
}
```

Values Can be accessed using mapping[100] which will give you 123.
If you want to convert it into string like you specified do the following.

```
const mapString = Object.keys(mapping).reduce((acc, curr) =>
  `${acc}${curr}:${mapping[curr]},`,
"").slice(0, -1)
```

It will give you this output `"100:123,200:456,300:789"`

### Update

For generating mapString, use the following. Thanks, @Soc for the suggestion.

```
const mapString = Object.keys(mapping).map(key => `${key}:${mapping[key]}`).join(',');
```

Comment: I personally prefer: `const mapString = Object.keys(mapping).map(key =>
  \`${key}:${mapping[key]}\`).join(',')`

Answer (score 0):

First create an object

```
var obj = {}
```

Then loop over it like

```
$(".selection:checked").each(function(){

    $selection_id=$(this).data('selection_id');
    $swatch_id=$(this).data('swatch_id');
    obj[$selection_id] = $swatch_id;
});
```

it will create an object something like :

```
{"100": 123, "200": 456, "300": 700}
```

you can change value of 100 like:

```
obj[100] = 1000
```

Then To convert into a string:

```
Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, val) => {
   acc.push(`${val}:${obj[val]}`); 
   return acc;
},[]).join()
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest method using the javascript object you can achieve this

```js
var mapObj = {};
$(".selection:checked").each(function(){


    var selection_id= $(this).data('selection_id');
    var swatch_id= $(this).data('swatch_id');
    //insert value in object
    mapObj[selection_id] = swatch_id;

});
// print object
console.log(mapObj);

// fetch particular key value
console.log(mapObj[100]);

// change value of object 
mapObj[100] = 1000;
console.log(mapObj);

// convert to string 
var string = "";
$.each(mapObj,function(index,val){
  string += index+':'+val+','; 
});
string = string.replace(/(^\s*,)|(,\s*$)/g, '');
console.log(string);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input class="selection" data-selection_id="100" data-swatch_id="123" type="checkbox"  name="vehicle1" value="Bike" checked> I have a bike<br>
    <input class="selection" data-selection_id="200" data-swatch_id="456" type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" value="Car" checked> I have a car<br>
    <input class="selection" data-selection_id="300" data-swatch_id="789" type="checkbox" name="vehicle3" value="Boat" checked> I have a boat<br>
```